# Visual Studio 2010 External Tool Go To Location

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I've created a custom external tool for myself using Vera++ for code formatting.  I got it working in Visual Studio 2010 through the external tool options.  I currently have all the output from Vera++ going to the output window in VS2010.  My question is, is there any way that I can set up my output so that visual studio will let me double click a line, and it will bring me to the line number?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you pattern your output after the error messages in Visual Studio this will happen automatically. `1>c:\users\john\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\monkey\main.c(5): error C2065: 'x' : undeclared identifier` for instance. The important part is (I think) file_name(line_number):.

Comment: This may work automatically but I think the output directory of the external tool matters.  It may have to be the same directory as where the code lives.